# Interpreting random survival forest mortality

Tags: r, survival, random-forest

I'm trying to follow [random survival forests](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1645). The `ensemble mortality` for $x_i$ is estimated by $ M_{e,i}=\sum_{j=1}^nH_e(T_j|x_i)$. Which means - sum over all death/censor times `j`, and for each such time get the averaged ensemble estimation for $x_i$ in time $j$.

I think that this means that for each tree in the ensemble, we detect the terminal node `h` in which $x_i$ sits, and sum its CHF $H_h$ over all possible points in time.

Under the `conservation of events`, this simply means sum the number of deaths in the terminal node of each tree in the ensemble! Is this correct? Is this is how its implemented in the `R` package? (can't read R for the life of me). If this is indeed so simple, why isn't it stated in the paper?